# Dynamically resize a centered PixiJS canvas and it's contents while keeping the ratio

Tags: javascript, html, css, pixi.js

I've been trying many solutions to find a way to center a pixiJS canvas on the window that would keep the ratio and would resize the contents too.

All I want is that the canvas keep his ratio and can't be shrinked when resizing the window. A little particularity is that the canvas fill the entire window when we are on smartphone or tablet (when orientation is landscape).

The best I can get is this example : http://www.thierrygallus.com/game/

I've used the media-queries but it doesn't keep the ratio and can be shrink when we diminuate the window's height too much. Here is the code :

```
/* all other device that are really small */
@media (max-width: 576px) {
    .background {
        background-color: #2f3640;    
    }

    .canvas {
        width: 98%;
        margin: 1%;
    }
}

/*Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up) */
@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .background {
        background-color: #2f3640;    
    }

    .canvas {
       width: 98%;
       margin: 1%;
    }
}

/* Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .background {
       background-color: #2f3640;    
    }

    .canvas {
       width: 98%;
       margin: 1%;
    }
}

/* all other devices that are big */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .canvas {
       height: 80%;
       width: 80%;
       margin: 4.5% 10%;
       padding: 0;
    }
}

/* NO ROTATION ALERT FOR DEVICES UPPER THAN 992PX (screen computers) */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .background {
       width: 100%;
    }

    .rotate-alert {
       display: none;
    }
}

/* DISPLAY FULLSCREEN WHEN DEVICE UNDER 992PX ARE IN LANDSCAPE ORIENTATION */
@media (max-width: 1200px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    html, body {
       height: 100%;
       margin: 0;
    }

    .background {
       background-color: #2f3640;
       width: 100%;
    }

    .canvas {
       height: 96%;
       width: 98%;
       margin: 0.5% 1%;
    }

    .rotate-alert {
       display: none;
    }
}
```

I assume that the best option will definitely be JavaScript but I'm still a beginner and all the fiddles I've seen couldn't work.